# Where is amazon simpledb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

Usually one can find amazon service using the search feature, but simpledb yields nothing.

I know it's not an active project but has it disappeared completely?

If not, how to find it in the console?

Comment: There is no console. You can  try https://aws.amazon.com/code/javascript-scratchpad-for-amazon-simpledb/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct link from the AWS console, but the service still active (https://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/)

To manage your data you could give a try to the [SdbNavigator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sdbnavigator/ddhigekdfabonefhiildaiccafacphgg) chrome extension.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/ points to a description of the service, not the service itself. Is there no way to access the service if you're not already a user?

Comment: @ben simpledb never really had a console.  It seems like maybe once upon a time you could list your domains and maybe create/delete them but that was about it... it never had a full-featured console like DynamoDB does.  Everything is still accessible via the API.

Comment: @Michael ah! alright I did not know that some aws services don't have a console UI! Thanks a lot for the info. Make it an answer maybe?

Comment: How many people use SimpleDB? Is it a recommended database for a new project?

Comment: @Defozo according to this Reddit thread here it is not recommended: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/2iuw11/cant_find_simpledb/ it is more or less abandoned by AWS nowadays again according to this Reddit thread.